# How to update 3 tables using one query in JPA?

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data

I have 3 tables UserDetail, RequestorDetail and AddressDetail. UserDetail is having userId(PK), userName, AddressDetail is having city and suburb, and RequestorDetail is having reqEmail and reqPhone.

I want to update all these details using one query. As of now, I m using 3 different Queries as below.

```
@Modifying
    @Query("update UserDetail u set "u.userName = :userName, u.password = :password where u.userEmailId = :userEmailId")
    int saveUserDetailData(@Param("userName") String userName, @Param("password") String password,  @Param("userEmailId") String userEmailId);

@Modifying
    @Query("update RequestorDetail r set r.requestorEmailid = :requestorEmailid, r.requestorPhone = :requestorPhone where r.userId = :userId")
    int saveRequestorDetailData(@Param("requestorEmailid") String requestorEmailid,
            @Param("requestorPhone") String requestorPhone, @Param("userId") int userId);

@Modifying
    @Query("update AddressDetail a set a.city = :city, a.suburb = :suburb where a.userId = :userId")
    int saveAddressDetailData(@Param("city") String city, @Param("suburb") String suburb,
            @Param("userId") int userId);
```

Can anyone please tel me how to use all these in single Query?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use only one query? I'm asking because in SQL (which JPA is based on) you can't update multiple tables at the same time. What you need to do is use a transaction which does all 3 queries and only commits after the three have executed.

Comment: Can you please tel me how to use transaction? I searched on same, but I dint get clear idea. Can you please give me an example?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't use JPA, I don't know how to precisely open a transaction or execute a query in it. How do you usually do it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to update multiple tables with single sql query.
See https://community.oracle.com/thread/2225393

You'll have to split this it into different queries.